# OWASP Zap alert names

Tags: automation, owasp, zap

I am looking for documentation describing all possible alert names in ZAP. Web search is not bringing anything useful, but I am writing an automated test that will detect any injection vulnerabilities of a target. Currently, I have only detected 'Remote OS Command Injection', but I would like to know the exact spelling of other potential ones e.g., SSI injection, or XML External Entity. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ScannerRules) you can find the list of all the rules that Zap loads, and those rules are what generates the alerts. You should have the rule id in the alert generated by Zap, so you can use that. Also, you customize some rules thresholds for your need - all documented on Zap's wiki.

Comment: We also have a list of the IDs here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/develop/src/doc/scanners.md
You're better off using the IDs rather than the alert names as those can be localized :)

Comment: The doc with IDs is no longer there, would you happen to have an updated location? Thanks

Comment: The file has moved to [here](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/develop/docs/scanners.md)

Comment: Not sure about that, each alert has it's own description in code - not sure how easy it is to find them